# separate class for drawing sprites, class doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sprite

i'm working on some sample game using cocos2d to get more practise and I have a problem with classes. Here's my example:

someShapes.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface palleteOfShapes : CCLayer 
{
    NSMutableArray *shapesArray;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *shapesArray;
-(void)drawPallete;
@end
```

someShapes.m

```
#import "palleteOfShapes.h"

@implementation palleteOfShapes
@synthesize shapesArray;
-(void)drawPallete

{
    shapesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Icon.png",@"A.png",@"questionMark.png",nil];
    for (int i=0; i<shapesArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *imagestring = [shapesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:imagestring];
         NSLog(@"i value: %i",i);
        sprite.position=ccp(100*i,350);
         NSLog(@"image added:%@",imagestring);
        [self addChild:sprite];
         NSLog(@"count: %d",[shapesArray count]);
    }        
    NSLog(@"pallete was completed");
    [shapesArray removeLastObject];
    NSLog(@"count:%d",[shapesArray count]);

}
@end
```

in the main layer I do:

```
palleteOfShapes *newPallete = [[palleteOfShapes alloc]init];
[newPallete drawPallete];
```

I expected that these sprites will appear on my main layer, but they don't.
NSLog shows all messages but no sprites.

So if you can, please tell me what's wrong.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add sprites to "palleteOfShapes" layer, but you never add them or "palleteOfShapes" to main layer.

Comment: well, I thought if I'll call drawPallete in the main layer, sprites will "think" they have to work on the main layer and draw their self on the layer :) probably it was stupid thinking. Can you tell me how to add these sprites from one class to the main layer?

Comment: You have to have things in scene in order to draw them, either directly or through other things. After you create "newPallete" in your main layer's init or whatever method, add it to your main layer: [self addChild:newPallete]. Also make sure that you added your main layer to the scene.

Comment: wow, I don't know why I thought that I don't need to add it to the scene :D now everything works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `-(id) init` method and try some initialisation there.

Comment: I have implemented init method in my main layer. If i'll do the same for my pallet layer, then it'll draw everything on separate layer not the main one. I think.